# How to find class in the closest tag?

Tags: javascript

How can I find class in a closest tag using Java Script? Need to find 'customer' class in .  The example as below:

```
       <tr>
            <td class="customer">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cust)
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="decisionList">
                    <option value="0" selected></option>
                    <option value="1">None</option>
                </select>
            </td>
       </tr>
```

I tried this in JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#decisionList").forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("change", function () {

    var selectedOptionIndex = this.options[this.selectedIndex].index;  //this works perfectly
    var invoiceDateText = this.closest('tr').find('customer').textContent; //this doesn't work

// ...some other code
```

Comment: Swap `find` with `querySelector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
document.querySelector("#decisionList").addEventListener('change', function() {
  const selectedOptionIndex = this.options[this.selectedIndex].index;
  const invoiceDateText = this.closest('tr').querySelector('.customer').textContent;
});
```

Comment: should I use const or var? Is there any significant difference?

Comment: @Muska yes. There is a difference. https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e

Answer (score 0):

The `closest` method uses the `querySelector` to find the closest.

```js
    var invoiceDateText = this.closest('.customer').textContent;
```

This should then search the `DOM` towards the document root for the closest element with the customer class.

If you wanted to search for the closest `tr` with a cell with `customer` class than you would modify that to.

```js
    var invoiceDateText = this.closest('tr>.customer').textContent;
```